# Invalid number for table and primary key

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I am creating a table for license, which is made up of 2 attributes from one table and one from the other. The license type and customer is in the main customer table and License_ID in another, as only certain types of customers can have a License_id.

I want to create a License table which has a primary key of License number and then the types and customer_ids for that License number.

This error occurs when trying to create the table, I am trying to do it so when the table is created it only takes the License_number's which are not 0/null. I also want to make the License_number the primary key, as well as the foreign key and the other 2 attributes foreign keys.

How can I do this?

```
CREATE TABLE License AS SELECT
DISTINCT License_number, License_type, cust_id
FROM yoda_60
WHERE License_number !=0;
```

> Error report -
>       ORA-01722: invalid number
>       01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
>       *Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
>       *Action:   Specify a valid number.

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (Oracle?)

Comment: You need to show the types of the columns in the source table.

Comment: add the two table structure and small data so that Query can be made to create the required table with required attribute. For mySql users mysql documentation https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-select.html is helpful

Answer (score 1):

Presumably `License_Number` is a string.  So, put the comparison in single quotes:

```
WHERE License_number <> '0';
```

What is happening is that the comparison to a number is causing *all* `License_Number`s to be converted to numbers -- and some are not numeric.  Hence, the error.

This will also filter out `NULL` values, but you can be explicit:

```
WHERE License_number <> '0' AND License_number IS NOT NULL;
```